# How to signal incoming call to Bluetooth correctly?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, pjsip

In my Voip App there is of course support for bluetooth headsets and cars' bluetooth interfaces.
How can I signal an incoming (voip) call correctly, so that the incoming number is shown in the car's display?

The app uses pjsip, everything is working fine, even audio over bluetooth.

When an incoming call is detected, the bluetooth connection is opened and (maybe here my error starts) the audio stream is opened to play the ringtone (the `mode` parameter is set to `MODE_RINGTONE` in this case).

```
    public void startBluetoothAudio(int mode) {
    try {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

            if (isSystemBluetoothEnabled()) {
                appRedirected = true;
                audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            }

            audioManager.setMode(mode);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Uclog.error("Exception caught starting bluetooth audio.", e);
        appRedirected = false;
    }
}
```

What then happens is:

The car instantly shows this as a running call (time is counting up) and no "accept/deny" buttons appear. only a "hangup" button. 
When I press hangup, the call is actually *established* then. pressing hangup again, correctly terminates the call.

My mistake must be in the signalling of the incoming call. How can I tell a headset that a call is ringing, so that the media buttons of the headset react correctly?

It is very clear, that I miss something important here as I currently have no clue how to send the incoming number so it gets displayed on the car's monitor.

Any help greatly appreciated!

If you need to see more or have additional questions, please just ask!

Thanks, Gris

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. Still in that state.